# Angular 2 Web API calling Get

Tags: angular

I am calling a Get API from angular 2 it Sends the data  in this Format bellow.I need to show picture(large) from this result how can i Do this.

## image Get Request Response

[image]

here is my Admin.component.ts class code

### Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteDefinition, Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {LoginComponent} from '../components/login.component';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
    templateUrl:'../../app/layouts/admin.html',
    selector:'Admin',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})


export class AdminComponent {
randomQuote: string;
private _data: Observable<any[]>;



  constructor(public http: Http) {
this.getRandomQuote();
  }


getRandomQuote() {
  this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .subscribe(
      data => this._data = data.json(),
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('User api call')
    );
}

  logError(err) {
    console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
  }
}
```

here is my admin.html code

### html

```html
<Admin>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:2em; background-color:#DCDCDC;">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="data?.results[0].picture.large" class="img-circle" alt="pic" /><br />
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li> <a [routerLink]="['Hello']">Users</a></li>
            <li><a >Groups</a></li>
            <li><a >Products</a></li>
            <li><a >APIs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="page-header ">
            <h1>
                Admin Portal
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content padding has-header">
            <router-outlet>

            </router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</Admin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.http.get(...).subscribe(data => this.data = data.json());
```

```
<img [src]="data?.results[0].picture.large">
```

Comment: error occurs `GET http://localhost:3000/data?.results[0].picture.large 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Where did you add the HTML I posted above?. You need to add it to a template of the component. where `this.data` gets assigned. If you want to do something different, please add more details to your question.

Comment: I have my html template separate in htm file

Comment: Did you add the `[]` around `src`. The error message indicates that the URL is taken literally instead of being evaluated by Angular.

Comment: Can you please add the full code of your component that demonstrates how you are using it to your question?

Comment: I showed it in my answer, I mentioned it in a comment above, you still don't have the `[]` around `src`. This is why the code is not evaluated but taken literally.

Comment: after inserting the above code `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: Sounds like the response doesn't look like you posted in your question. `data.results` returns `null` but your screenshots shows that the outermost object has a `result` property.

Comment: So, how do we proceed? :D